# How can I create an Grid with its first cell to be square in .Net Maui?

Tags: .net, xaml, grid, maui

I want to create a Grid with its first cell to be square, i.e. its height equals its width which is decided by screen width.
I was thinking something like below but it didn't work.

```
<Grid RowDefinitions ="{DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width}, *">
... ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: you will likely need to do this in code, not XAML

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this in code.

I created a demo ,you can refer to the following code:

```
public class GridPageCS : ContentPage
{
    public GridPageCS()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100) }
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition()
            }
        };

        grid.Children.Add(new BoxView
        {
            Color = Colors.Green
        });
        grid.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Row 0, Column 0",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        });

        Title = "Basic Grid demo";
        Content = grid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a perfect Square cell and the remainder filled regardless of portrait/landscape sizing, we can make use of a view model to help.

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<Grid Width="{Binding GridWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
      Height="{Binding GridHeight, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding SquareCellSize}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding SquareCellSize}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="squareCell" Fill="LightSteelBlue"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="nextCell" Fill="Orange" Grid.Row="{Binding NextRow}" Grid.Column="{Binding NextColumn}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the above, we are using an `OneWayToSource` binding to retrieve the `Width` and `Height` of the parent `Grid`. We use that to compute the dimensions of the Square cell as well as the placement of the next cell (i.e. it could be to the right of the Square cell, or it could be to the bottom).

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SquareCellSize))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(NextRow))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(NextColumn))]
    private double _gridWidth = 100;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SquareCellSize))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(NextRow))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(NextColumn))]
    private double _gridHeight = 100;

    public double SquareCellSize => Math.Max(Math.Min(GridWidth, GridHeight), 1);
    public int NextRow => GridHeight >= GridWidth ? 1 : 0;
    public int NextColumn => GridHeight >= GridWidth ? 0 : 1;
}
```

If you want to avoid using properties in a view model, then, you could go the converter route. The following uses a `IMultiValueConverter`, in particularly, it uses `MultiMathExpressionConverter` from `CommunityToolkit.Maui`:

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mauiSquareApp"
             x:Class="mauiSquareApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:MultiMathExpressionConverter x:Key="MultiMathExpressionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition.Height>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter}" ConverterParameter="max(min(x0, x1), 1)">
                        <Binding Path="Width" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                        <Binding Path="Height" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RowDefinition.Height>
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter}" ConverterParameter="max(min(x0, x1), 1)">
                        <Binding Path="Width" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                        <Binding Path="Height" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ColumnDefinition.Width>
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="squareCell" Fill="LightSteelBlue"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="nextCell" Fill="Orange">
            <Grid.Column>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter}" ConverterParameter="max(sign(x0 - x1), 0)">
                    <Binding Path="Width" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                    <Binding Path="Height" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Row>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiMathExpressionConverter}" ConverterParameter="1 - max(sign(x0 - x1), 0)">
                    <Binding Path="Width" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                    <Binding Path="Height" Source="{x:Reference grid}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Row>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```